# Communication between ejs template and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I'm trying to modify an exiting code of a web app made with node, express, ejs and jquery. I'm working on a section that presents a list of products. Each product can be edited. When you click on the edit button you get a modal that is filled out with the current info if the product.
The problem i'm having is with the picture associated with the product. The current code does not pull the current image so you have to enter it again. I must modify the code to make it pull the current picture. But for that I need to be able to communicate between ejs template and jquery and viceversa. But i have not been able to for the moment.

Here's the relevant part of the ejs code

```
<div class="container panel wide-event-panel" id="table-content" >
                <% for(var i=0; i< product.length; i++) {%>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 no-padding">
                            <img src="<%= product[i].banner %>" alt="Promo image" class="imgIzq"/>
                            <p class="text-next-2-img"> <%= product[i].name %></p>
                        </div>
```

...
                                <%= product[i]._id['$oid']%>
                                <%= i%>
                                 Editar
                            
                        
                    <% } %>

And the modal in the same ejs template

```
<div id="prod-custom-template" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
```

...
                    
                    
                      <% for(var i=0; i< image.length; i++) { %>
                        
                            " alt="...">
                             " >
                        
                      <% } %>

And this is the jquery functino that fills the product info.

```
fillProductData = function(data, productButton){
    document.getElementById('prod-input-name').value=data.name;
    var type = data.product_type === "product" ? "Producto" : "Servicio";
    document.getElementById('selectedType').value=data.product_type;
    document.getElementById('typeSpan').innerHTML=type;
    document.getElementById('prod-price').value=data.price;
    document.getElementById('prod-category').value=data.category;
    $('#descriptionTextarea').val(data.description);        
   if(data.keywords){
       document.getElementById('prod-keyword').value ='';
        for(i = 0; i<data.keywords.length; i++){
            document.getElementById('prod-keyword').value += data.keywords[i] +",";
        }          
   }
    document.getElementById('prod-modal-header').innerHTML="Editar Producto/Servicio";
    $('#acceptEditProduct').removeClass("hidden");
    $('#acceptNewProduct').addClass("hidden");
    var images= $('div.item').find('img');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    console.log(images);
    for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){ 
        var checkingImage = images[i];                        
        if(checkingImage.src === data.banner){
            var $this = $(checkingImage)[0].parentElement;                      
            $($this).addClass('active');
            var $indicator= $('.indicator')[i];
            $($indicator).addClass('active');
        }
    }
    if($('.active').length === 0){
        var $firstImage = $('div.item')[0];
        $($firstImage).addClass('active');
        var $firstIndicator= $('.indicator')[0];
        $($firstIndicator).addClass('active');
    }
};
```

These are 2 separate files, there is a third file with the express app that sends the images to the ejs template. I have tried a lot of things, but what i should do is to send the list of images to the jquery function so that i can add as the first object of the list the current picture. Any help on how to do that kind of communication would be very appreciated.

Comment: which runs where? node + express + ejs typically means you're using that to generate the page that the browser loads. Once that happens, there is no "ejs" anymore, what the browser gets is pure HTML without any templating left in it (which in fact why you use ejs. So you can work with templates, but the result is clean proper HTML). If your jQuery runs in the browser, what node+express+ejs does is completely irrelevant and only the browser-visible DOM matters.

Comment: Great, didn't know that. Then, express build the app who calls 'app.get("/productos-servicios" ... res.render('products.ejs', {image: images, product : products, user: req.user, selectedCompany: req.session.selectedCompany, toast: toast});' which is the ejs template. The template calls 'var scripts = ['javascripts/products.js'];' which is the jquery script. So, I suppose that what I need to be able to send the images list to the products.js too. Can I do that?

Comment: right, so the request for `yourdomain.moo/productos-servicios` by the browser causes node+express+ejs to take `products.ejs`, replace everything templaty in that file with real values and builds a completely-templating-less result, then sends that back to the browser. The template itself doesn't call anything, it just gets placeholders replaced with real values. Look at the source that your browser sees as response (view-source the page in the browser) and that's what you're really working with.

Comment: Then what i'm missing and have no idea yet is how to take control of the images list from the jquery function. Any ideas? I need to send the images list from the express app to the jquery function so i can modify it there.

Comment: You have the image list already linked into the products.ejs render call, so just do something with that in your template file. You can turn it into a series of `<img ...>`, or just serialise it in as a `<script>var images = {%= JSON.stringify(images) %};</script>` or something?